# Inquiry about some modifications to one of the Firestore plugins

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

first of all , i am using the following plugin which lemme sort results depends on nearby users

```
plugin name :  geo_firestore_flutter 0.1.6
link on dev : https://pub.dev/packages/geo_firestore_flutter
```

It's a very cool plugin , After hard and a lot of testing, Every time it gives me results according to the required distance, very accurately and wonderfully.

depend on readme file , they said the following

> Geo Queries  GeoFirestore allows you to query all documents within a
> geographic area using the method getAtLocation like following

```
final queryLocation = GeoPoint(37.7853889, -122.4056973)

// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 0.6 kilometers
 GeoFirestore(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('places'))
 .getAtLocation(queryLocation , 0.6).then((value){

 });
```

now as what i said After hard and a lot of testing, Every time it gives me results according to the required distance .

now the problem is when provide `.limit(10).where('test',isEqualTo: '1')` to the previous method like following

```
GeoFirestore(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('places').limit(10).where('f',isEqualTo: '1'))
  .getAtLocation(const GeoPoint(queryLocation , 0.6).then((value){

});
```

it give me red line and error message says the following

```
The argument type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

So I modified the main file for `geo_firestore_flutter 0.1.6` like following

i am here will paste the whole original file without modification

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:geo_firestore_flutter/src/geo_hash_query.dart';
import 'package:geo_firestore_flutter/src/geo_hash.dart';
import 'package:geo_firestore_flutter/src/geo_utils.dart';

///
/// A GeoFirestore instance is used to store and query geo location data in Firestore.
///
class GeoFirestore {
  late CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference;

  GeoFirestore(CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference) {
    this.collectionReference = collectionReference;
  }

  ///
  /// Build a GeoPoint from a [documentSnapshot]
  ///
  static GeoPoint? getLocationValue(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    try {
      final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data != null && data['l'] != null) {
        final location = data['l'];
        final latitude = location[0];
        final longitude = location[1];
        if (GeoUtils.coordinatesValid(latitude, longitude)) {
          return location;
        }
      }
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error occurred when getLocationValue: ' + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  /// Sets the [location] of a document for the given [documentID].
  Future<dynamic> setLocation(String documentID, GeoPoint location) async {
    var docRef = this.collectionReference.doc(documentID);
    var geoHash = GeoHash.encode(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    // Create a Map with the fields to add
    var updates = Map<String, dynamic>();
    updates['g'] = geoHash;
    updates['l'] = [location.latitude, location.longitude];
    // Update the DocumentReference with the location data
    return await docRef.set(updates, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

  ///
  /// Removes the [location] of a document for the given [documentID].
  ///
  Future<dynamic> removeLocation(String documentID, GeoPoint location) async {
    //Get the DocumentReference for this documentID
    var docRef = this.collectionReference.doc(documentID);
    //Create a Map with the fields to add
    var updates = Map<String, dynamic>();
    updates['g'] = null;
    updates['l'] = null;
    //Update the DocumentReference with the location data
    await docRef.set(updates, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }

  ///
  /// Gets the current location of a document for the given [documentID].
  ///
  Future<GeoPoint?> getLocation(String documentID) async {
    final snapshot = await this.collectionReference.doc(documentID).get();
    final geoPoint = getLocationValue(snapshot);
    return geoPoint;
  }

  ///
  /// Returns the documents centered at a given location and with the given radius.
  /// [center]      The center of the query
  /// [radius]      The radius of the query, in kilometers. The maximum radius that is
  ///               supported is about 8587km. If a radius bigger than this is passed we'll cap it.
  /// [addDistance] Whether to process data and add distance property to returned documents, defaults to True.
  /// [exact]       Whether to process data and remove documents that are further than specified radius, defaults to True.
  ///
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getAtLocation(
    GeoPoint center,
    double radius, {
    bool exact = true,
    bool addDistance = true,
  }) async {
    // Get the futures from Firebase Queries generated from GeoHashQueries
    final futures = GeoHashQuery.queriesAtLocation(
            center, GeoUtils.capRadius(radius) * 1000)
        .map((query) => query.createFirestoreQuery(this).get());

    // Await the completion of all the futures
    try {
      List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documents = [];
      final snapshots = await Future.wait(futures);
      snapshots.forEach((snapshot) {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          if (addDistance || exact) {
            final latLng = doc.data()['l'];
            final distance = GeoUtils.distance(center, GeoPoint(latLng[0], latLng[1]));
            if (exact) {
              if (distance <= radius) {
                doc.data()['distance'] = distance;
                documents.add(doc);
              }
            } else {
              doc.data()['distance'] = distance;
              documents.add(doc);
            }
          } else {
            documents.add(doc);
          }
        });
      });
      return documents;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed retrieving data for geo query: ' + e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

modification that i made is only replaced `CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>` to `dynamic`

from

```
class GeoFirestore {
  late CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference;

  GeoFirestore(CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference) {
    this.collectionReference = collectionReference;
  }
```

to

```
class GeoFirestore {
  late dynamic collectionReference;

  GeoFirestore(dynamic collectionReference) {
    this.collectionReference = collectionReference;
  }
```

then i test it again , no errors , the results is cool , i am free now to use `.limit()` `.where()` also the distance query was the same and correct .

now my question is : I am very concerned about my modification. I am not sure that my modification will not affect the results of the required distances, although I did not notice any effect . but i still ask my self why the plugin owner did not make this modification ? i cannot ask him because the issues section in plugin is not available can anybody please who have experience of Firstore geo query tell me if there is really no affect of distances after my modification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found me .

So, I don't think your modification will work (although you are saying the results are as expected). In `queriesAtLocation`, it uses the radius that was provided to determine the 9 geohash queries that are surrounding the provided lat/lng. Then it runs ALL of those queries and only *after* that does it sort by distance. So by limiting those 9 individual queries, you might be missing the closest result to your center point. If you're trying to save Firestore costs, there is a better way to do so. Simply run `getAtLocation` in a loop, increasing `radius` until you get a result. This is what I do.

Also, anytime you replace a typed parameter with `dynamic`, you could run into errors if you're not careful. What I would do is create a second constructor with `Query<Map<String, dynamic>>` as the parameter. Then the IDE will inform you of any type errors as you go.

I just opened up issues and PRs on the repository (I didn't realize they were closed). Feel free to submit a PR if you're able to add a limit since that would be a useful feature!

Comment: i am so happy you answering my question finally , i am really totally confused about how could i use getAtLocation  in loop if it is basically unlimited its self !. or do you mean to loop it in case i used my modification ?  if not, any example about that loop you talking about i would be extremely thankful

Comment: and what do you mean of  9 geohash queries . did you mean 10 ? in .limit(10)?